# Creating a table in Hive with error "permission denied for relation"

Tags: hive, hue

I'm using Hive through Hue.  I tried to create a table using following schema:

```
create table temp_batting (col_value STRING);
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
Driver returned: 1.  Errors: OK Hive history
file=/tmp/hue/hive_job_log_4d872c22-e58c-4f9a-9573-442c2be4664b_1970355385.txt
FAILED: Error in metadata:
MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Add request
failed : INSERT INTO "COLUMNS_V2"
("CD_ID","COMMENT","COLUMN_NAME","TYPE_NAME","INTEGER_IDX") VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?)  NestedThrowables: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
ERROR: permission denied for relation COLUMNS_V2) FAILED: Execution
Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a system problem (Linux?). The user that's executing this command probably doesn't has write access on the folder where postgres tables (files) are stored.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your PostGresql Hive Metastore is not configured properly. The Hive user should have the permissions to modify the database. More information is [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_hive_metastore_configure.html#topic_18_4_3_unique_1__title_524_unique_1).

Answer (score 0):

You need change the permissions of your databases. In the path of your database you need ensure that you can write on database. If you know the path run this command on the directory:

for linux:

$ sudo chmod -R a+w .